# Godot crashing when exporting to Android

Tags: android, godot

## problem

Godot crashes when I try to export a project to Android on this screen:

[image: screenshot]

How can I fix this?

I've done everything in the tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/games/engines/godot/godot-export#launcher_icons), but it still isn't working for me. I've tried retrying it three times, but it still isn't working for me, and I couldn't find anything saying how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which Godot version are you using? Are you on Linux or Windows?

Comment: @magenulcus 3.3.3, and fedora linux

Comment: Do you get any error message? Does Godot also crash when you try to export an empty project?

Comment: @magenulcus No error message, and yes

Comment: There may be an issue with your build environment or your Godot version is somehow currupt. Have you tried a more recent Godot release like 3.3.4 or 3.4.4? You could also try to build it in a VM and see if the issue arises there as well.

Comment: No, nevermind. I figured out the problem, and apparently I had a folder with the same name as the project where I was exporting it to, but I didn't realize it was there. Thanks!